# Turn on out of office but exclude emails where the sender's address exists on some specific domains

Tags: microsoft-outlook, out-of-office

I would like to be able to turn on out of office to all incoming emails except for a few choice domains e.g. any emails my account receives should be replied to with an out of office message except for messages where the sender's address in on domain1.com or domain2.com who should not receive out of office replies.

Reason: I will be leaving my current employer this weekend but will be maintaining a relationship with a few clients through my old company and do not wish to cause confusion in telling them I have left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new rule that specifies as follows:

- Check messages when they arrive -- all messages
- Reply using a specific template -- then choose the template
- except if from people or distribution list --

You would have to create both the out of office template to be used, as well as the distribution list (or select all the individuals from your address book) to be the exception.